# Upload iOS device token for Push Notification

Tags: ios, server, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, token

I would like to know how to manage the iOS device token App & Server Side.
First, I registered my app to receive remote notification. So, I got the device Token.

My questions are :

**App Side**

- When Should I send the token to the server ?
- If Many times, how often ? Each log Request ?
- I should send the token to the server directly from this method `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` or store it, and send it in an other method ?

**Server Side**

- Once I have the token on the server, how can I know if the token is still valid ? Or that I should delete it cause the device token is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**App side**

It's better to upload it in every api request to track the user devices as he may login in his account from multiple devices , so you should have array of device tokens in server , or only one token if you want to track the last device the user is active with so , store token from `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` say in user defaults and upload it for every api request

**Server side**

The token is still valid if the php script used to send it returns success operation but if not that may also mean .pem file is incorrect